# Send data from client side JS code to Struts 2 ActionSupport class

Tags: struts2, client

I've seen some post about sending and building jgGrids from actions registered on struts.xml web application that uses this libraries. But I've not seen yet any about how to catch the processed data from a grid. My code:

```
jQuery("#bedata").click(function(){
    jQuery('#rowed3').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel);
    var gridData = jQuery("#rowed3").getRowData();
    var postData = JSON.stringify(gridData);
    alert("JSON serialized jqGrid data:\n" + postData);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CargaTabla.action",
        data : {
            jgGridData: postData,
            customData: "someinfo"
        },
        dataType:"json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
            alert("success");
         },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

`id = betadata` button send data to "`CargaTabla.action`", an action registered in Struts 2 configuration file. Data is properly serialized as a JSON string. `ClassActionImpl` is the class that catch this action, is there any way to get the information sended by Javascript? Has Struts 2 any way to get this data without use JSP request or something like that, just Java code in the same `ClassActionImpl.execute()`? Some hidden parameter?

Thank you.

struts.xml

```
<action name="CargaTabla" method="guardarUsuario" class="org.json.JSONRespuestaTabla"> <result name="success" type="json"> 
<param name="includeProperties">jgGridData</param> 
</result>
</action>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok Umesh. I new in this community I am not able to score you, yet. :( Sorry. I appreciate so much your effort.
Well, I fixed the issue. It seems like struts doesnt like 'POST' method to autofill attributes:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
```

Instead:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
```

And it access automatically to setter methods anyway its name. If I have an attribute name "customData" that means it will automatically access to its setter method and fill with data sended from client. If there is no attribut called like a certain parameter, Struts 2 just ignore the data. There is no need to configure anything else in struts.xml file. Just the action:

```
        <action name="CargaTabla" method="guardarUsuario" class="org.json.JSONRespuestaTabla">
        <result name="success" type="json"/>
    </action>
```

This is very interesting and strange at once; no need to declare any parameter. -param- in struts.xml tag is used only to SEND data to web client. You cannot filter if you want or not to fill some attribute of the ActionClass. I would like to know more about data from client management in Strut2. Maybe there is some interceptor to help on that.

Thank you again.
Raph

Comment: Do you know how to make Struts 2 able to recieve data in "POST" mode. Has "GET" mode any limitation on data lenght or something like that?

Comment: i am not sure if post/get can be an issue and yes get do have limitation on the data being sent and in last its against the rule get for getting and post for sending data to server.will look in to the issue for sure and +1 for fixing it up :)

Answer (score 0):

Well Struts2 has build in mechanism to receive data being sent by the request to the action class.
In your case i believe you are sending following data\

```
jgGridData: postData,
customData: "someinfo"
```

Not sure in what format this code is sending data to action especially `jgGridData`.But for the second parameter all you need to do is to define a property in your action class with name `customData` and its getter and setter, struts2 param interceptor in request execution process will look for property with similar with the request parameter name and will try to set the value in respected property in your action class.

```
public class ClassActionImpl extends ActionSupport{

    private String customData;
    private String jgGridData; // I am assuming data as string you can change it as per your data type

//getter and setter for both above properties

   public String execute() throws Exception{
    //can use both the above properties here as they will be filled by fraework
   }

}
```

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your reply. The problem is that when CargaTabla.action is called from Struts 2 framework, jgGridData accessor that its called is GETTER, not SETTER, so, I am not able to get the information sended by client side:                      <result name="success" type="json">
                <param name="json">jgGridData</param>
            </result>                                                             it calls to jgGridData GETTER, not SETTER, so i cant catch the data from client.

Comment: @Raph i am afraid i am not able to under stand this completely.can you describe a bit more

Comment: Thank you again Umesh. Ok, JavaScript is sending jgGridData parameter to an ActionSupport class. This action has been declared at struts.xml configuration file, and I added parameters in order to get the information from the client (jgGridData parameter, that is an String). Well, I do that adding this tag in the action: <param name="json">jgGridData</param>. But it makes the action call the getter method, not the setter, so It is not filling the jgGridData attribute with the data from the client. Its just callig the getter. How can I configure struts.xml in order to fill jgGridData attribute?

Comment: Namaste. I mean, I want to take parameters (data) sended by a javascript ajax to an Action registered in my struts.xml. How the class that supports this action can acced to this data? I thought that Struts 2 had an authomatic way to fill these parameters. But it is not calling the setter method to fill. With my configuration (above) just call getter method, that is used to send data from server (action class) to client. I want just the other face: from client to server. I'm just lost.

Comment: @Raph: got what you are trying to do ,can you just post your `struts.xml` and `action class`? since the param you have set will work when action will send success and it will call the getter.

Comment: Hello. The fragment is:         <action name="CargaTabla" method="guardarUsuario" class="org.json.JSONRespuestaTabla">
            <result name="success" type="json">
                <interceptor-ref name="params"/>
                <param name="includeProperties">jgGridData</param>
            </result>
        </action>

Comment: interceptor-ref is just added now to see if it works (ignore it, it seems it fails in parsing for now, somethig wrong in format. Anyway, I dunno if its solving something). method "guardarUsuario" is properly called, and it calls the getter for jgGridData attribute. But Im not able to fill his attribute, that its my goal. Calls in ActionClass are called properly, but they have just some lines to follow the debuggin.